# How can you ask about a particular conjugation?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Say for example you want to know how to conjugate the Spanish verb "contar" for present tense "yo". The correct answer is "cuento", but how can you ask?

Does it make sense to ask "How do you conjugate 'contar' to present tense 'yo'?". Perhaps "... for present tense 'yo'"?

This knowledge would be helpful in any case you don't know how to conjugate a verb, especially when dealing with irregulars like "Contar". I want to know how to ask the question in English.

Comment: Can you clarify in what situation you need to ask this? Does it help to know that _yo_ is the first person singular?

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted the whole conjugation I would ask: "What is the present indicative of *contar*". If I just wanted a specific instance I would ask: "What is the first person singular present indicative of *contar*". Obviously I would change that if I wanted a different person or number. Note you do need to specify whether you want the indicative or subjunctive.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @mdewey is correct, but if you want something more informal, you could say

> How do you conjugate *contar* in the first person singular?

People will tend to assume you want the present tense.  But if you want this to be explicit, you could say

> How do you conjugate *contar* in the present tense, first person singular?

The other ones have the following names:
*tú* - second person singular 
*él, ella, ello, usted* - third person singular 
*nosotros* - first person plural 
*vosotros* [or *ustedes*, depending on the country] - second person plural 
*ellos, ellas* [, *ustedes*, depending on the country] - third person plural

And the simplest way of all:

> How do you conjugate *contar* with *yo*?

(Optionally, add "in the present tense" at the end.)

It might not be elegant but it will work!